# Borrowing a structure which reference Strings - value borrowed here after partial move

Tags: rust

I'm learning Rust and I have the following error message:

> note: move occurs because value has type `std::string::String`, which
>   does not implement the `Copy` trait

I believe it's because I have some fields in a `struct` that are `String` (even though I'm borrowing `&cfg` - hence the `value borrowed here after partial move` ?).

Am I correct? Any idea how to fix it instead of using `Copy` or is it the only solution?

See below a SSCCE

```
fn main() {

    let file_cmd = String::from("file1.conf");

    let cfg = Config {
        project: Project::Project1,
        env: Environment::Test,
        cmd: Command::Command1 { file: file_cmd },
    };

    match cfg.cmd {
        Command::Command1 { file } => {
            build_path_file(&cfg, &file);
        }
        _ => ()
    }

}

fn build_path_file(config: &Config, file: &str) -> PathsConf {
    let local_path = format!("{}/{}", &config.local_path(), file);
    let s3_path = format!("{}/{}", &config.s3_path(), file);
    PathsConf {
        local: local_path,
        s3: s3_path,
    }
}


enum Project {
    Project1,
    Project2,
}

enum Environment {
    Test,
    Live,
}

enum Command {
    Command1 { file: String },
    Command2 { file: String },
}

struct Config {
    project: Project,
    env: Environment,
    pub cmd: Command,
}

impl Config {
    pub fn new(project: Project, env: Environment, cmd: Command) -> Self {
        Self {
            project,
            env,
            cmd,
        }
    }


    pub fn s3_path(&self) -> String {
        String::from("s3/config")
    }

    pub fn local_path(&self) -> String {
        String::from("local/config")
    }
}


struct PathsConf {
    pub local: String,
    pub s3: String,
}
```

The error message:

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `cfg`
  --> src/main.rs:13:29
   |
12 |         Command::Command1 { file } => {
   |                             ---- value moved here
13 |             build_path_file(&cfg, &file);
   |                             ^^^^ value borrowed here after partial move
   |
   = note: move occurs because value has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Comment: The match on `cfg.cmd` is what triggers the partial move of `cfg`. You can borrow it to clear the error: `match &cfg.cmd {`

Comment: Perfect - thank you very much